# Is there a way to run a Raspberry Pi Python code using SQLite on boot using systemd?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am designing a code that appends data to a SQLite database on boot using a Raspberry Pi. The systemd service worked well when I was originally using txt files, but now that I transferred to using SQLite for the robustness, the service fails to function on boot. I have tested the setup multiple times with txt files and the SQLite database. It works on boot using the txt files but not with the SQLite database. When running the code normally (not during boot), both the txt file and SQLite database work fine.

I have tried changing my systemd settings to start the code later in the boot up process (i.e., type=idle or After=graphical.target), but the SQLite database still fails to run on boot. Any suggestions on how to handle this issue?

The service used on boot is as follows: VoltCurr.service

```
[Unit]
After=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/wrhsc1310/Python/VoltCurrWrite.py
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The Python code used to record the voltage and current data is as follows:

```
import time
import sqlite3
import Adafruit_ADS1x15
import board
from adafruit_ina219 import ADCResolution, BusVoltageRange, INA219
i2c_bus = board.I2C()  # uses board.SCL and board.SDA
# i2c_bus = board.STEMMA_I2C()  # For using the built-in STEMMA QT connector on a microcontroller

ina219 = INA219(i2c_bus)

# optional : change configuration to use 32 samples averaging for both bus voltage and shunt voltage
ina219.bus_adc_resolution = ADCResolution.ADCRES_12BIT_32S
ina219.shunt_adc_resolution = ADCResolution.ADCRES_12BIT_32S
# optional : change voltage range to 16V
ina219.bus_voltage_range = BusVoltageRange.RANGE_16V

# Create an ADS1115 ADC (16-bit) instance.
adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()

# Choose a gain of 1 for reading voltages from 0 to 4.09V.
# Or pick a different gain to change the range of voltages that are read:
#  - 2/3 = +/-6.144V
#  -   1 = +/-4.096V
#  -   2 = +/-2.048V
#  -   4 = +/-1.024V
#  -   8 = +/-0.512V
#  -  16 = +/-0.256V
# See table 3 in the ADS1015/ADS1115 datasheet for more info on gain.
GAIN = 2

Time_Const=0
elapsed_time=0
i=0

while True:
    Time_Const=Time_Const+elapsed_time
    start_time=time.time()
    Time = (Time_Const) #Time in seconds
    Current = (ina219.current) #Current in mA
    Voltage = (adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN))*(0.0000625) #Voltage in Volts
    connection = sqlite3.connect('PowerData.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Data (Time, Voltage, Current) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",[Time,Voltage,Current])
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    i=i+1
    time.sleep(0.01)
    end_time=time.time()
    elapsed_time=end_time-start_time
```

Service Error Message:

```
● VoltCurr.service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/VoltCurr.service; enabled; vendor p>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-05-30 19:04:48 BST; 2>
    Process: 435 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/wrhsc1310/Python/VoltCurrWr>
   Main PID: 435 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 1.951s

May 30 19:04:36 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started VoltCurr.service.
May 30 19:04:47 raspberrypi python[435]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May 30 19:04:47 raspberrypi python[435]:   File "/home/wrhsc1310/Python/VoltCurrWrite.py", line 43, in <module>
May 30 19:04:47 raspberrypi python[435]:     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Data (Time, Voltage, Current) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",[Time,Voltage,Current])
May 30 19:04:47 raspberrypi python[435]: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Data
May 30 19:04:48 raspberrypi systemd[1]: VoltCurr.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 30 19:04:48 raspberrypi systemd[1]: VoltCurr.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 30 19:04:48 raspberrypi systemd[1]: VoltCurr.service: Consumed 1.951s CPU time.
```

Comment: When the service fails, what are the errors?

Comment: I just checked and the failure lists "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: Data" with Data being my table created in the database. I used another code to create the "Data" table prior to running the code.

Comment: For us to help you, you would need to include an [mcve] in your question: both code and a systemd unit file sufficient to reproduce the behavior you're asking about.

Comment: Sorry. I have now added the service and data recording code to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to open your database from your script's current working directory:

```
    connection = sqlite3.connect('PowerData.db')
```

Since you are not being explicit about where this file is located, this means that when running via systemd, a situation in which your default working directory is `/`, you're trying to open `/PowerData.db`, which presumably doesn't exist.

You need to either use the full path to your file in your code, or explicitly set [`WorkingDirectory`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#WorkingDirectory=) in your systemd unit file.

You may also want to set [`User`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=) if you are running the systemd unit from a system location (like `/etc/systemd/system`).